# Anchor tag not working for force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites

I have PKB implemented and associated it with a force.com site. This site does not work with URL anchor tag.

Generally when we have multiple sections on a site and we add a section name with anchor in URL, that URL takes me directly to that section.

However in my force.com site it still keep me on top of page.

Eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump#Net_worth will take me to Net worth section